# Fatal two-task communication protocol error in oracle 10 g

Tags: oracle, qtp

I'm using QTP 10. 
Trying to connect to Oracle DB via oracle client 10.2(windows xp).
I had prev oracle 9i & i've upgraded it to 10.2 thought it would resolve. 
But still i'm getting "fatal two-task communication protocol error".

Is there any solution for that .
i see the same client version is working with windows 7 & oracle 10.2.

Appreciate your help..

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. Also, please give us more details about this error - either more of the error message you see output, logs, the kind of behaviour that cause this or generally more context. Also let us know if there's anything else you've tried to fix this issue and how that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ADODB to connect to Oracle 10 and 11 from QTP (from VBScript in generall).
The code to connect is:

```
Set connection = createobject("adodb.connection")
connection.open "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};" + _
      "Server=host:1521/database_sid;Uid=username;Pwd=password;"
```

where:
`host` - is a server name where Oracle is running
`1521` - is a port number (1521 is default port, but could be different on your system)
`database_sid` - is a SID of the database
You need to ask your database administrator for these values.
This code requires Oracle Instant Client. 

You need to download proper package for your system (Win 32, Win 64 etc.) from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html

Unpack it to any directory and place this directory in a PATH environment variable.

and then, the code to execute queries and get results looks like this:

```
Set rs = createobject("adodb.recordset")
rs.open "SELECT fieldname FROM table WHERE etc.", connection
while not rs.eof 
   value = rs.fields( "fieldname" )
   .....
loop
```